# Setting up an Amazon Server with Go Daddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns

I am trying to set up an Amazon Server to host a dynamic website I'm currently creating. I have the domain bought on GoDaddy.com, and I believe that what I've done so far has linked the domain to my Amazon account.
I followed this tutorial : http://www.mycowsworld.com/blog/2013/07/29/setting-up-a-godaddy-domain-name-with-amazon-web-services/
In short, this walked me through setting up and Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service) and Amazon Route 53. I then configured the DNS Servers, and my website now launches properly on the domain.

I'm not sure on the next step from here, but I would like to set up:

-A database server

-Anything else that might be necessary to run a dynamic website.

I am very new to hosting websites, and semi-new to web development in general, so the more in depth the better.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to create the site to define what you need to run the site. Yes you will probably need to run a database of some kind. Yes your site will have some dependencies. What you come up with defines those. What are you going to create?

Comment: @Matt I have the HTML files as well as the python files to run the actual website. I need a database to store login information, and I need dependencies like Flask on the server side as well

Answer (score 0):

You have two options on AWS. Run an EC2 server and setup your application or continue to use the AWS managed services like S3.

[Flask apps can be hosted on Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) and 
[your database can be hosted on RDS (Relational Database Service)](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/). Then the [two can be integrated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html).

Otherwise, spin up your own t2.micro instance in EC2. Log in via `ssh` and set up the database server and application like you have locally. This server could also host the (currently S3 hosted) static files too.

I have no idea what your requirements are, personally I would start with setting up the EC2 instance and go from there as integrating AWS services is without knowing what you need is probably not the easiest first step.

[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) might be another option. They host their services on AWS and give you an end to end solution for deploying and [running your python code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction) without getting your hands dirty setting up servers.